# Seeing where the import got called

Tags: java, eclipse, import, java-package

For example, if I perform some shortcut on `import java.util.HashMap;` in a class, I want Eclipse to show the lines where I instantiate HashMaps and call HashMap methods in that class.

Comment: been a while since i used eclipse but I seem to remember that if you double click the import (eg double click File in the import java.io.File) then it will highlight where they are in the package. Out of interest: why?

Comment: Ctrl-F (find) or Ctrl-Shift-G (find workspace references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + G` for references of the class or `Ctrl + G` for declarations.

or

Right click your class (in your Java editor) and go to either References or Declarations.

[image]

I only use Ctrl + Shift + G for searching for references.

Inside the Class, you can find references to the class turning on the option in the menu bar as marked. Clicking on a class or variable, it will highlight the references/occurrences in your class.

[image]

Comment: I don't think my question was clear.  For example, if I perform some shortcut on `import java.util.HashMap;` in a class, I want Eclipse to show the lines where I instantiate HashMaps and call HashMap methods in that class.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I will update my answer with this however the question and the answer will be a bit messed up with information about two things.

Comment: Sweet. Now that you explained, your question makes sense. :)

Comment: Yep, your new answer solved my question, thanks!  Just a tip for anyone reading, be sure to click on the actual class (last part of the import) to mark occurrences.  Clicking anywhere earlier in the import won't show anything since that's the package, not the class.